# Python Pipenv Install: EnvironmentError: Permission Denied

Tags: python, python-3.x, dependency-management, pipenv, virtual-environment

Trying to install python-decouple inside a pipenv shell:

```
(projectname) username@host: pipenv install python-decouple
```

But I'm getting this following error:

```
Installing python-decouple…
Error:  An error occurred while installing python-decouple!
Error text: Processing /home/username/.cache/pipenv/wheels/6d/5a/2d/acfg...422fd/python_decouple-3.3-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: python-decouple

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/projectname-J2Y6DseW/lib/python3.6/site-packages/__pycache__/decouple.cpython-36.pyc'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

I realize that I can install this package from outside the pipenv shell using:

```
python3 -m pip install --user python-decouple
```

But this would mean that this dependency wouldn't be managed by Pipenv when someone tries to replicate my project environment using Pipenv...

How can I get around this issue and what is the reason for it, what kind of permissions could I set on the file to overcome it?

Answer (score 1):

#### Use it at your own risk:

The following solution works:

Run:

```
sudo chmod 777 /home/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/projectname-J2Y6DseW/lib/python3.6/site-packages/__pycache__
```

After this, try installing with pipenv again from within the pipenv shell.

I don't know whether this is a good solution or not, so please correct me if you have a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents here:

I would modify the `requirements.txt` (every virtual environment should have one, or at least setup one for maintaining dependencies), by adding package for `python-decouple`. The current version is 3.3, so add this somewhere in the file: `python-decouple==3.3` and re-run the virtual environment or install `requirements.txt` again.

See this [link](https://pypi.org/project/python-decouple/) for more information on this package.

Comment: Generated a requirements.txt from the Pipfile, added python-decouple==3.3 and then tried to regenerate the Pipfile from the requirements.txt. 

Receiving the exact same error... 

Thank you for your suggestion though!

Comment: Try doing this inside of the virtualenv i.e within the `(projectname)` environment, `pip install python-decouple`. If you receive any error related to `pip` then update the `pip` package with `upgrade` command.

Comment: Just tried this... It's giving me the exact same error.